# Adding custom object to Group in paperJS

Tags: javascript, paperjs

In PaperJS, only regular types seem to be able to be added to a Group. Whenever I try to append the group with a custom object I get the error `item._remove is not a function`

Whenever I create my own object, for instance:

```
function textBox(point, width) {
    this.box = new Path.Rectangle({
        point: point,
        size: new Size(width,40),
        strokeColor: new Color(0,0,0,0.1),
        fillColor: 'white',
        strokeWidth: 1
    });

    this.box.onMouseUp = function(event) {
        cursor = this.point + new Point(5,2);
    }

}
```

and try to append this to a group:

```
var testGroup = new Group();
testGroup.appendTop(new textBox(new Point(0,0), 400));
```

The error shows up. My question is thus: how do I add custom objects to a group? Surely I can't be expected to either manually create each individual object or otherwise manipulate them all on an individual level without using Group dynamics. It seems I have to, just like every other type in PaperJS, make my object extend Item, but I so far have failed to get it to accept my constructor for it. I'm wondering what is required for it to be accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, there currently is no built-in mechanism to extend `Paper.js` classes apart from compiling them along with the library.
So for simple cases like the one that you seem to encounter, I would use a factory function that instantiates my custom object and then interact with it as with any other `Paper.js` object.
For example, if your custom object is a box with a text in it, you can instantiate a group with a rectangle and a text in it and then just interact with this group.

Here is a [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.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) demonstrating the solution.

```
function createMyTextBox(point, content) {
    // Create a text item
    var text = new PointText({
        point: point,
        content: content,
        fontSize: 36,
        fillColor: 'red',
        justification: 'center'
    });

    // Create a rectangle around the text
    var rectangle = new Path.Rectangle({
        rectangle: text.bounds.scale(1.2),
        strokeColor: 'black'
    });

    // Create a Group that will wrap our items.
    var group = new Group([text, rectangle]);

    // Return the group
    return group;
}

// Create 2 text boxes
var textBox1 = createMyTextBox(view.center, 'text 1');
var textBox2 = createMyTextBox(view.center + [0, 100], 'text 2');

// You can use text boxes like regular items.
textBox2.translate(100, 0);
textBox2.scale(0.8);
```